# Link shortening, url redirection

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, redirect

I'm working on a link shortening website, https://i9i.xyz/ ,
So after getting the long url value from the database I'm echoing a js script,(window.location) which redirects the user to that long url. I'm not sure if this is the correct method for redirection, for a link shortening web service

Comment: I wouldn't handle the redirect in JS but rather do `header('location:' . $theRealUrl)` in PHP. If you use JS, the client needs to download your javascript, parse it and execute it just to be redirected. It will also only work on clients that can parse and execute JS. Using `header()` in PHP would work on any client that can handle a redirect header (which is way more than can handle JS)

Comment: To add onto what @MagnusEriksson is saying, a user could also disable JS completely and then they would be left on your site without a redirect at all. I also wonder how it deals with unfurl.